# Encrypted remote backup

Tags: backup, encryption

2013, Still the same question but with a twist :

( [How to do rsync-like encrypted backup?](https://superuser.com/questions/251174/how-to-do-rsync-like-encrypted-backup) )

> I want to save a backup of my data on a remote server, but never want
>   the backup server to see the data unencrypted. Editing a single file
>   and backing up should not result in everything being encrypted and
>   sent again. The remote server should preferably not even know the
>   directory structure (and especially not the directory names).
>
> Is there such a solution?

In this question from 2011 the answer points to a non official package. 
Is there some solution that is "well known" ?

(other similar question "[Best linux backup software that is most like Time Machine](https://superuser.com/questions/153895/best-linux-backup-software-that-is-most-like-time-machine)" but this is even older and points to a GUI app which is not what I'm seeking)

Comment: If you would like to draw attention to an older question where you feel the answers are outdated or could use some improvement, please place a bounty on the question.

Comment: @slhck bounty is a nice idea when you have 55k+ rep. But when you struggle with 133 rep, leaving a 50 rep bounty leaves you even more naked. Anyway I've found that tartarus is "outdated" in the way that it has not evolved for a long time but it seems that it is still working very well as it's a wrapper. Another cool thing is : it's opensource, GPLv3 and ... on github https://github.com/wertarbyte/tartarus

Comment: I absolutely understand. Could've offered a bounty if you wanted, but I'm glad you found that the tool worked for you.